# Beam I/O connector (python) for SOAP and/or REST

Tags: apache-beam

We are building a data warehouse which combines data from a lot (n) of sources. Theses sources are made available to us in various ways like, csv files, direct database access, SOAP and REST.

.csv and direct access are covered extensively in the Apache Beam documentation, however there seems to be little (if any) coverage of SOAP and REST. We have no problem getting REST and SOAP data first, then use the data to instantiate a pCollection and let the pipeline handle it from there. However, a pattern is emerging that we think calls for a different approach:

1. Query an endpoint to get a list of other endpoints that serve the actual data.
2. Iterate over said list to retrieve the data

In some cases, the total amount of records retrieved like this will be in the tens of millions (possibly more in the future).

The question: How can we retrieve this data efficiently using Beam, making use of parallel processing? Do we need to write a custom python I/O connector and if so, where can we find an example of a SOAP or REST (or any http request really, We searched extensively but all we found was a single link and even that was stale)

Or alternatively: The lack of documentation and questions about this subject makes us think that Beam is in fact not the correct tool for this particular job. Is this correct?

Not sure if entirely relevant: We use Google Dataflow as a runner and Biqquery for storage (for now).

Comment: The beam site says Stack Overflow is the place for user questions. This question has been up for over a week _with all 20 views accounted for within our organisation_. So "The lack of documentation and questions about this subject makes us think that Beam is in fact not the correct tool for this particular job" seems to be the answer for Apache Beam in general, not just this particular question. Looks like it's just a toy for academics, too bad I guess.

Comment: I believe the feature your are looking for is https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/16/splittable-do-fn.html, in which you can split the initial list of endpoints and do parallel processing. The API exists in python sdk but support from dataflow backend is still under active development (as of today) if I understand correctly.

Comment: @YichiZhang This seems promising indeed, thank you for your input. Too bad they use file IO as an example though, a single example of a http request in an IO connector could have saved the day. This project I'm working on is on the verge of being scrapped because while there are hundreds of articles describing high level concepts, the documentation on what syntax to use to actually implement those concepts is virtually non existent. Trial and error and reading source is not a process I can sell to my employer. Again thanks for your input, but I don't think I can salvage this.